# how to make an array of strings into a key value pair object, making the value an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, key-value

I've got an array of strings like so:

```
[
    "hl7_file_type_1.msgtype",
    "hl7_file_type_1.filename",
    "hl7_file_type_2.msgtype",
    "hl7_file_type_2.filename",
    "hl7_file_type_3.msgtype",
    "hl7_file_type_3.filename"
]
```

I am trying to convert this into a key value pair object like so (`expected result`):

```
{
"hl7_file_type_1": ["msgtype","filename"],
"hl7_file_type_2": ["msgtype","filename"],
"hl7_file_type_3": ["msgtype","filename"],
}
```

Here is how I am attempting this:

```
let tmp = {};
for (let i = 0; i < this.regexArray.length; i++){
      let split = this.regexArray[i].split('.');
      tmp[split[0].trim()] = split[1].trim();
    }
    console.log('Key Value')
    console.log(tmp);
```

Here is what is returning:

```
{
    "hl7_file_type_1": "filename",
    "hl7_file_type_2": "filename",
    "hl7_file_type_3": "filename"
}
```

How can I change my function to return the `expected result` like mentioned above

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Is this really TypeScript at all?  The example code here would probably give compiler warnings with `tmp[split[0].trim()]` because `tmp` is inferred as type `{}`.  If this has nothing to do with TypeScript maybe the tag should be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  "hl7_file_type_1.msgtype",
  "hl7_file_type_1.filename",
  "hl7_file_type_2.msgtype",
  "hl7_file_type_2.filename",
  "hl7_file_type_3.msgtype",
  "hl7_file_type_3.filename",
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [prop, type] = curr.split(".");
  if (!acc[prop]) acc[prop] = [type];
  else acc[prop].push(type);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `map` and then `reduce`.

```js
const data = [
  "hl7_file_type_1.msgtype",
  "hl7_file_type_1.filename",
  "hl7_file_type_2.msgtype",
  "hl7_file_type_2.filename",
  "hl7_file_type_3.msgtype",
  "hl7_file_type_3.filename",
];

const res = data
  .map((d) => d.split("."))
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ((r[k] ??= []), r[k].push(v), r), {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of mapping and reducing should do it

```js
const input = [
    "hl7_file_type_1.msgtype",
    "hl7_file_type_1.filename",
    "hl7_file_type_2.msgtype",
    "hl7_file_type_2.filename",
    "hl7_file_type_3.msgtype",
    "hl7_file_type_3.filename"
]

const result = input.map(i => i.split(".")).reduce( (acc,[key,value]) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: [...(acc[key] || []), value]
  }
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Creating new arrays and objects again and again, is it performant enough?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee probably - for an array of 6 items (or even 600!) A larger number, not so much!